# Adding a back/cancel button in the scan page in ZXing

Tags: android, zxing

I have an Android Application and I am scanning barcodes via ZXings library. I have integrated it to build with my Android Application so there's no more need for the user to install the ZXing Barcode application separately.

I can scan and handle results and cancellations perfectly. However, to make the application more intuitive to users, I want to add a "Cancel" or a "Back" button on the scan page itself.

I have searched through the internet and [found this blog](https://medium.com/@marta/bar-code-scanner-in-android-with-custom-layout-zxing-2ab92d9d744c#.vh93s2mxd). That blog said that ZXing updated their library to make Customization easier, however, [customization seems a bit limited from what the GitHub page shows](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded#customization) and there's not much samples for how to customize the UI.

The blog also showed options for a back/cancel buttons, however, [the GitHub link seems broken](https://github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal#custom-layout) and does not point anywhere.

Has anyone tried and successfully managed to use a custom UI Layout for scanning with ZXing?

Answer (score 0):

As the [class comment said](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/4210396bd04e8ee3310209640c362989d4ab4109/zxing-android-embedded/src/com/journeyapps/barcodescanner/CompoundBarcodeView.java):

> To customize the UI, use BarcodeView and ViewfinderView directly.
>
> BarcodeView is a `ViewGroup` so you can add childs back/cancel `button`s

Comment: Does that mean that I can provide my own layout and use that `ViewGroup` as BarcodeView? I'm reading the linked class right now and I'm having quite a hard time dissecting it. If you can provide your "way" of solving this then I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is that the custom layout linked in most blogs are dead. [I found a working link here.](https://github.com/hansreichenbach-okta/zxing-android-minimal/blob/master/sample/src/main/res/layout/custom_capture_layout.xml) Basically, what we want to do is to provide a custom layout file and use it via:

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setCaptureLayout(R.layout.custom_capture_layout);

//do more things here if you want

integrator.initiateScan();
```

And it will use the custom layout you provided. Just in case the above link dies, here is the code I used:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright (C) 2008 ZXing authors
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
 -->
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <SurfaceView android:id="@+id/zxing_preview_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderView
        android:id="@+id/zxing_viewfinder_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zxing_result_view"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/zxing_result_view"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:baselineAligned="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="@dimen/zxing_standard_padding">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

                <ImageView android:id="@+id/zxing_barcode_image_view"
                    android:layout_width="160dip"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxWidth="160dip"
                    android:maxHeight="160dip"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    tools:ignore="ContentDescription"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_format"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_format_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_type"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_type_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_time"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_time_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_meta_text_view_label"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_meta"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:paddingRight="@dimen/zxing_half_padding"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_meta_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_minor_text"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_contents_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textSize="22sp"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                    <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_contents_supplement_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:textColorLink="@color/zxing_result_text"
                        android:paddingLeft="12dip"
                        android:autoLink="web"
                        android:textIsSelectable="true"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zxing_result_button_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

            <Button style="@style/zxing_ResultButton"
                android:visibility="gone"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/zxing_status_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/zxing_transparent"
            android:text="@string/zxing_msg_default_status"
            android:textColor="@color/zxing_status_text"/>

        <Button android:id="@id/zxing_back_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:height="60dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:text="@string/zxing_button_cancel"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

I just copy pasted it with no customization at all. It has a "Cancel" button when you initiate scanning. I hope this helps anyone who encounters dead links.